# Jquery adding and removing class dynamically

Tags: jquery, class

I am trying to add the class"selected"  when a link is clicked and when the user click on the next link , I want to remove the previously "selected" class and add "selected" to the link clicked..

-Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.news a').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
});

<div class="news-w">
            <div class="news" id="getnews-1">
            <a href="#" >topic</a>
            </div>
            <div class="news" id="getnews-2">
            <a href="#">topic</a>
            </div>      
            <div class="news" id="getnews-3">
            <a href="#" >topic</a>
            </div>      
            <div class="news" id="getnews-4">
            <a href="#">topic</a>
            </div>      
            <div class="news" id="getnews-5">
            <a href="#">topic</a>
            </div>                      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.news a').click(function(){
         $('.selected').removeClass('selected')
         $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To add a toggle effect when adding a class or an ID, Use this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var count = 1;
                $('#ddown').click(function(){
                count++;
                    if (count % 2 == 0) {
                         $('#ddown').addClass('dropup');
                         $('#ddown').removeClass("dropdown");
                    }else{
                        $('#ddown').removeClass("dropup");
                        $('#ddown').addClass("dropdown");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Yea i know, I came to the party very late.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.news-w div.news a').click(function(){
       $('div.news-w div.news a.selected').removeClass("selected");
       $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Also you are having an invalid HTML. You have more than 1 element with the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternate solution is:

```
var prevLink = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.news a').click(function(){
         if(prevLink) prevLink.removeClass('selected');
         prevLink = $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$('.news a').click(function(){
$('.news-w').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

it will be removed automatically just class **selected** in **div class='news-w'**

If u use this :

```
$('.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

when u want to add more element **a** into DOM out from 
**div class='news-w'** it will be removed too..